# C# and T-SQL Insert User Defined Table into a another table not working

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, procedure, user-defined-types

I plan to send a data table to the SQL Server database, and `INSERT` the new rows. There will be multiple insert posts for each row in the program. No errors are returned but the rows aren't added to the table. The product table has got more columns than `[dbo].[CSV_ADDProducts]` but I have selected the columns it would map to.

Can anyone spot the mistake I'm making or suggest a better way to do this? Thanks

SQL Server stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUpload_AddBulkProducts]
 @uploadedTable [dbo].[CSV_ADDProducts] readonly
 AS
BEGIN TRY
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Products]
([Product Item],[Product SKU],[Product Name],[Product Active],[Product Selling Price],[Product Description],[Product Purchase Description],[Product VAT Code ID],[Product Last Update])
SELECT
[Product Item],[Product SKU],[Product Name],[Product Active],[Product Selling Price],[Product Description],[Product Purchase Description],[Product VAT Code ID],[Product Last Update]
FROM @uploadedTable
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH
```

C# program

```
DataTable POSTCSVCREATE = new DataTable();
        POSTCSVCREATE.Columns.Add("Product Item", typeof(SqlString));
        POSTCSVCREATE.Columns.Add("Product SKU", typeof(SqlInt64));
        POSTCSVCREATE.Columns.Add("Product Name", typeof(SqlString));
        POSTCSVCREATE.Columns.Add("Product Active", typeof(SqlString));
        POSTCSVCREATE.Columns.Add("Product Selling Price", typeof(SqlMoney));
        POSTCSVCREATE.Columns.Add("Product Description", typeof(SqlString));
        POSTCSVCREATE.Columns.Add("Product Purchase Description", typeof(SqlString));
        POSTCSVCREATE.Columns.Add("Product VAT Code ID", typeof(SqlInt64));
        POSTCSVCREATE.Columns.Add("Product Last Update", typeof(SqlDateTime));
        
        foreach (ParseQBProduct.Product i in create)
        {
            var rows = VAT.Tables[0].Select();
            string VATID = "1";
            foreach (DataRow row in rows)
            {
                if (row["VAT Name"].ToString() == i.VAT.ToString())
                {
                    VATID = row["VAT ID"].ToString();
                }
            }
            string dt = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");

            if (i.ProductSellingPrice.Trim() != "")
            {
                POSTCSVCREATE.Rows.Add(i.UniqueTitle, Convert.ToInt64(i.manunum), i.name, i.ProductActive, (SqlMoney)Convert.ToDecimal(i.ProductSellingPrice), i.ProductDescription, i.ProductPurchaseDescription, Convert.ToInt64(VATID), (SqlDateTime)Convert.ToDateTime(dt));
                recentAddedfile.Add(i.manunum+" -- " +i.UniqueTitle);
            }
           
        }
        Authentication.LoginUC.instance.Session.Procedure_UploadTable("spUpload_AddBulkProducts", POSTCSVCREATE);
```

User defined Table

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[CSV_ADDProducts] AS TABLE(
    [Product Item] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Product SKU] [bigint] NULL,
    [Product Name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Product Active] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [Product Selling Price] [money] NULL,
    [Product Description] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Product Purchase Description] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Product VAT Code ID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Product Last Update] [datetime] NULL
)
GO
```

When I run this, it does work as a query on the DBMS

```
DECLARE @Table AS [dbo].[CSV_ADDProducts]
Insert into @Table
Values ('test',1,'test name','true',10.44,'des','pdes',2,'2020-09-10 12:12:12.000')
EXECUTE spUpload_AddBulkProducts @Table
```

My source: https://www.sqlshack.com/table-valued-parameters-in-sql-server/

Comment: do you mean the c# table or the user defined table in the procedure? @Steve thanks

Comment: If no rows are inserted, that suggests your parameter, `@uploadedTable` doesn't have any rows in it.

Comment: @Steve thanks, np ill have a bit more of a read up on it. ill add a link for the source i used to code this but i do agree the error list didn't want the user defined Table type to be set when in CMD mode

Comment: Tahnks @Larnu, i put a break in c# program before the sql command was executed and the parameter had the row values in it

Comment: @Steve ah okay, thanks for checking

Comment: 2 questions.   1. Could you show the Table Type definition?  2.  How does this procedure behave outside of c#? From SSMS, from example.

Comment: @jim Thanks, i have added the user defined table sql above and the query on the DBMS that works. I think its the the query in the C# program or the data table im making mistakes on

Comment: I'd wrap it in try-catch (in the stored procedure) and check if any constraints are violated, like primary key, foreign keys, NULLs, the string values are longer than the fields, etc. Are there any triggers that may interfere?

Comment: Thanks @VladimirBaranov I have gone through it and changed the nvarchar from 50 to max. and added the try catch. the product table vat id is a foreign key, but i couldn't define the vat id in the user defined table as a foreign key. is this s a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the commented out code is what was not working. `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uploadedTable", DT);`
works fine

```
public bool Procedure_UploadTable(string procedure,DataTable DT)
            {
                DBConn.Open();
                using (var command = new SqlCommand(procedure) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure })
                {
                    command.Connection = DBConn;
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uploadedTable", DT);
                    //SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@uploadedTable", SqlDbType.Structured)
                    //{
                    //    TypeName = "[dbo].[TBLCSV_ADDProducts]",
                    //    Value = DT
                    //};
                    try
                    {
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        DBConn.Close();
                        return true;
                    }
                    catch(Exception e) {
                        DBConn.Close();
                        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
                        return false; }
                }
            }
```